# Python - Manage cursor connection outside context manager

Tags: python, sqlite, connection, decorator

I'm new at Python and I'm trying to build a start project to get into this language.

I created a SQLite3 DB and managed to make transactions with it.
Everything works fine.

I wanted to get deeper in Python so I've been searching and discovered **Decorators** and **Context Manager** and I was trying to implement these concepts on my Query Execution's functions. However, I'm stuck with a problem.

I've created a class that handles the open and close connection tasks.

**DB_ContextManager.py** class:

```py
class DB_ContextManager():
    def __init__(self, db_connection):
        self.db_connection = db_connection

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_connection)        
        return self.conn

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb): # obligatory params
        self.conn.close()
```

And also created **ConnectionDB.py** which is responsible for executing queries.

```
from Database.DB_ContextManager import DB_ContextManager as DB_CM

# Handles SELECT queries
def ExecuteSelectQuery(self, pQuery):
    try:
        with DB_CM(db_connection_string) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(pQuery)
            result = cur.fetchall()        
            return result

    except Exception as e:
        LH.Handler(log_folder, 'ConnectionDB', 'Queries', 'ExecuteSelectQuery', e)            
        raise DE.ConnectionDB_Exception()

# Handles INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs queries
def ExecuteNonQuery(self, pQuery):
    try:            
        with DB_CM(db_connection_string) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(pQuery)

    except Exception as e:
        LH.Handler(log_folder, 'ConnectionDB', 'Queries', 'ExecuteSelectNonQuery', e)            
        raise DE.ConnectionDB_Exception()
```

As you can see

```
with DB_CM(db_connection_string) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(pQuery)
```

is repeated in each function

To avoid this situation, **I'd like to create a Decorator function that encapsulates this piece of code**.
My problem is that the cursor 'dies' inside the ContextManager and, for example, ExecuteSelectQuery needs the cursor to fetch the return data after the query was executed.

I know it's a small project and thinking so long term in future may not be necessary. But, remember, it's a start project and I'm learning to apply new concepts.

---

**SOLUTION**

As @blhsing suggested, I return the connection object instead of the cursor in the ContextManager.

Also I handles `commit()` and `rollback()` in it.

So, summarizing:

**ConnectionDB.py**

```py
def ExecuteSelectQuery(self, pQuery):
    with DB_CM(db_connection_string, pQuery) as cur:
        result = cur.fetchall()
        return result

def ExecuteSelectNonQuery(self, pQuery):
    with DB_CM(db_connection_string, pQuery) as cur: 
        pass
```

and **ConnectionDB.py**

```
class DB_ContextManager():
    def __init__(self, db_connection, pQuery):
        self.db_connection = db_connection
        self.query = pQuery

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_connection)
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(self.query)
            self.conn.commit()
            return cur            

        except Exception as e:
            LH.Handler(log_folder, 'DB_ContextManager', 'DB_ContextManager', '__enter__', e)
            self.conn.rollback()
            raise DE.ConnectionDB_Exception()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb): # obligatory params
        self.conn.close()
```

Comment: But I want to encasulate `cur = conn.cursor()` and `cur.execute(pQuery)` in an external function and `ExecuteSelectQuery` will be in charge of fetching data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the context manager return the cursor instead of the connection object:

```
class DB_CM():
    def __init__(self, db_connection):
        self.db_connection = db_connection

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_connection)
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(pQuery)
        return cur

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb): # obligatory params
        self.conn.close()
```

so that the `try` block of `ExecuteSelectQuery` can be revised as:

```
with DB_CM(db_connection_string) as cur:
    result = cur.fetchall()        
    return result
```

and the `try` block of `ExecuteNonQuery` can be simply:

```
with DB_CM(db_connection_string):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works fine. I had not thought of 'with DB_CM(db_connection_string): pass`

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can move the exception handler inside the context manager too, to increase more code reuse.